# What is this quick release clamp?

Tags: quick-release

I obtained this surplus quick-release and I would like to buy a matching camera plate. Does anyone know what type this is?

It is about 2 1/2 inches square.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a plate for something really big & heavy like a movie camera.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a Manfrotto 577 clamp and it uses the 501PL sliding plate... it was used on video heads, but there's no reason it can't be used for other purposes as well.

Comment: The Manfrotto  501PL plate is available at B&H Photo. https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/553892-REG/Manfrotto_501PL_501PL_Sliding_Quick_Release.html